# Printing a randomly chosen variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a dice roller for the game Heroscape (So we can play with offshore friends). The dice for heroscape have 6 sides. 3 sides show skulls, 1 side has a symbol and 2 sides have a shield.

I've made it randomly generate 1 of those sides, but i'd like it to list off the results at the end (i.e. You rolled 6 skulls, 2 symbols and 4 shields).

Heres my current code:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    diceChoose = raw_input('Pick your dice. (Press 1 for a D20 roll, and 2 for attack /defense dice.) ')
    if diceChoose == ('1'):
        import random
        for x in range(1):
            print random.randint(1,21),
            print
        raw_input("YOUR DICE ROLL(S) HAVE COMPLETED. PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")
    elif diceChoose == ('2'):
        diceNo = int(raw_input('How many dice do you need? '))
        testvar = 0
        diceRoll = ['skull', 'skull', 'skull', 'symbol', 'shield', 'shield']
        from random import choice

        while testvar != diceNo:
            print choice(diceRoll)
            testvar = testvar + 1
            if testvar == diceNo:
                print ('YOUR DICE ROLLS HAVE COMPLETED')

        raw_input("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")

    else: loop = raw_input('Type 1 or 2. Nothing else will work. Press 1 to start the program again.')
```

What i've tried is a bunch of if statements, but i've realised that if I try print ('diceRoll') all I get is the whole array instead of the randomly selected dice roll.

I'm not sure how to save each diceRoll as it happens, so I can print that number later on.

(My thinking is something like

```
if diceRoll == 'skull' skullNo +1 
print('skullNo'))
```

Comment: Hello - Welcome to SO. If either [Blckknght's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351750/1993598) or [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351762/1993598) has helped you, please click on the green check mark next to our name. It will mean alot and will help other members of the site quickly find the most effective answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good data structure for you to use for this problem would be the `Counter` from the `collections` module in the standard library. It works a little like a dictionary, mapping objects to an integer count. However, you can add values to it and that will increment their count.

So, I'd do this:

```
from random import choice
from collections import Counter

diceNo = int(raw_input('How many dice do you need? '))
diceValues = ['skull', 'skull', 'skull', 'symbol', 'shield', 'shield']

counter = Counter()
counter.update(choice(diceValues) for _ in range(diceNo))

print("Rolls:")
for value, count in counter.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(value, count))

print ('YOUR DICE ROLLS HAVE COMPLETED')
raw_input("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")
```

The key line is `counter.update(choice(diceValues) for _ in range(diceNo))`. This calls `counter.update` with a "generator expression", which produces `diceNo` random roll results. If you haven't learned about generator expressions yet, I suggest checking them out, as they can come in really handy.

Comment: Took too long editing my original post (Hit enter to go down a line and it posted instead D:) 

Thanks so much for your replies! Unfortunately I'm not grasping this very well - your code makes the app crash. I assume I've done something wrong! 

I've added it in to my code (I'll definitely be reading up on generator expressions when I get home!) for now, by copying and pasting. When I select 2 after running the app, it closes immediately without showing anything. Same goes for the other guy's code up there! I apologise for my newbishness :(

Comment: Ah, I had a typo in my `import` statement. The correct module name is `collections` not `collection`. I've fixed it above. Your description of the experience though suggests you might want to change how you're running the program. When I ran the code above (by itself, not in your larger program) in Idle, I got a fairly helpful error message, ending with `ImportError: No module named collection`. Try running your program from a command prompt or IDE so you can see any exceptions you're causing. Debugging will be a nightmare without that!

Comment: I'm just saving these with my notepad app as test.py and double clicking. a command prompt window opens then immediately closes if theres an issue. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Sorryboss: Yes, there's definitely a better way to run a Python script, at least, while you're debugging. The simplest is to open a command prompt manually (run `cmd.exe` if you're on Windows), then type `python myscript.py` when you're in the right folder. An alternative that's a bit more complicated to set up, but easier once it's prepared is to use [an IDE](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments). I often use Idle, and IDE that's included in Python's standard library. It's not very fancy, but it works fine for most of what I need to do.

Comment: Ah, I already have IDLE installed apparently. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I changed a few parts of your code to make them more similar to *my* style - feel free to change them back if that helps.

Change your loop code to simply:

```
while True:
```

This accomplishes the same thing, except that it is more pythonic.

Then, tab in one and tell set number values for the `skull, symbol` and `shield`. In this case, we set it to 0.

```
skull = 0
symbol = 0
shield = 0
```

Next, change the code below the `diceNo = int(raw_input('How many dice do you need? '))` to this. It should be indented by one.

```
    for x in xrange(diceNo):
        import random
        choice = random.randint(1,6) 

        if choice == 1:
            skull +=1
        elif choice == 2:
            skull +=1
        elif choice == 3:
            skull +=1
        elif choice == 4:
            symbol =+ 1
        elif choice == 5:
            shield += 1
        elif choice == 6:
            shield += 1
```

This code repeats for the number of dice rolls needed. I then adds 1 to the variable associated with that name.

Directly below that, we display the info to the user.

```
print "You rolled %d skulls, %d symbols, and %d shields. Congrats." % (skull, symbol, shield)
```

Since you seemed to be having issues with the code, I decided to post it in its entirety.

```
while True:

    #Here we set the variables

    skull = 0
    symbol = 0
    shield = 0

    diceChoose = raw_input('Pick your dice. (Press 1 for a D20 roll, and 2 for attack /   defense dice.) ')
    if diceChoose == '1':
        import random
        for x in range(1):
            print random.randint(1,21),
            print
        raw_input("YOUR DICE ROLL(S) HAVE COMPLETED. PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")
    elif diceChoose == '2':
        diceNo = int(raw_input('How many dice do you need? '))

        for x in xrange(diceNo):
            import random
            choice = random.randint(1,6) 

            if choice == 1:
                skull +=1
            elif choice == 2:
                skull +=1
            elif choice == 3:
                skull +=1
            elif choice == 4:
                symbol =+ 1
            elif choice == 5:
                shield += 1
            elif choice == 6:
                shield += 1

        print "You rolled %d skulls, %d symbols, and %d shields. Congrats." % (skull, symbol, shield)

        raw_input("PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE.")

    else: loop = raw_input('Type 1 or 2. Nothing else will work. Press 1 to start the program again.')
```

Comment: I think `random.choice` from a list is more pythonic than a big series of `if`/`elif` statements. Data structures (even the basic ones) are good, use them!

Comment: This is more what I was thinking of, but I can't seem to get this working either. When I save and run the app it flashes up for a moment then closes. I think this indicates a syntax error, but I can't see one anywhere.

Comment: @sorryboss Hmmm... That is weird. I ran my code in windows on python 2.7.3 - are you using a different os? Perhaps it was your indentation - I will copy and paste the entire code later today (after I finished standardized tests, probably 11 am EST.)

Comment: Thanks again mate - i've got it working now, it was indeed my indentation. I was running the code via the command prompt which didn't show errors, but i've started using IDLE which is very informative!